# PyQt Signals not reaching outter class

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox, qt-signals

I am trying to write a code related to a QComboBox widget.
The ComboBox class is a nested/inner class inside the MyTreeAutoDisplay class (for this particular case, the TreeAutoWidget would be out **init** function).
The problem I have is that the signal from the ComboBox class, doesn't reach the signal from the MyTreeAutoDisplay class, and therefore, it doesn't trigger the show_combobox function.

Any clue what may I be doing wrong?

```
import queue
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic, QtCore, QtGui
import PyQt5
import PyQt5.QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QDialog, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSignal
import os
from matplotlib.widgets import Widget
import rospkg

import rospy
from kmr_msgs.msg import KMRStatus, NavState
from pathlib import Path
from anytree import Node, RenderTree
from anytree.exporter import DotExporter
import numpy as np


class TreeAutoWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        
        super(TreeAutoWidget, self).__init__()
        rp = rospkg.RosPack()
        pkg_path = rp.get_path("comar_gui")
        uifilepath = os.path.join(pkg_path, 'ui/combobox.ui')
        uic.loadUi(uifilepath, self)
        MyTreeAutoDisplay(self)

    def handle_exception(self, se : Exception):
        self.display_error(str(se))

    def display_error(self, msg : str):
        errorDialog = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
        errorDialog.setIcon(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Critical)
        errorDialog.setText("Error")
        errorDialog.setInformativeText(msg)
        errorDialog.setWindowTitle("Error")
        errorDialog.exec_()
        
        # LOAD DATA STRUCTURE

class MyTreeAutoDisplay(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    
    node_array = []
    top_nodes = []

    def __init__(self,parent_widget):
        super( QtWidgets.QWidget , self ).__init__()
        self.parent_widget = parent_widget
        
        # NODE STRUCTURE
    
        program = [] #father of everything (created for programming purposes but not displayed)
        car = []

        program.append(Node) 
        program[0] = Node("PROGRAM")

        car.append(Node) 
        car[0] = Node("Mercedes X", program[0])
        
        car.append(Node)
        car[1] = Node("Mercedes Y", program[0])

        # LOAD THE NODES INTO AN ARRAY
        
        for node in program[0].children:
                self.top_nodes.append(node)

        box_widget = self.ComboBox(self.top_nodes)
        box_widget.got_signal.connect(self.show_combobox)

        self.parent_widget.gridLayout.addWidget(box_widget)
        
    @PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)                   
    def show_combobox(self, index):
        rospy.logwarn(index)

    class ComboBox(QtWidgets.QComboBox):

        got_signal = PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, name="combobox_changed")

        def __init__( self, top_node_array):
            super( QtWidgets.QComboBox , self ).__init__()

            self.InsertPolicy.InsertAtBottom
            index = 0
            for node in top_node_array:
                self.insertItem(index, node.name) 
                index = index+1
            
            self.activated.connect(self.combobox_changed)

        @PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
        def combobox_changed(self, index):
            rospy.logwarn(self.currentText())
            rospy.logwarn(index)
            self.got_signal.emit(index)
```

Comment: The instance of `MyTreeAutoDisplay` (which is also useless, as it inherits from QWidget but isn't used as such) gets immediately deleted, and **all** its members that have no other reference get deleted too, including `show_combobox`. You either make some actual use of that instance or you don't use it. Also: 1. avoid using nested classes, they are rarely *actually* necessary, in most cases they only make code uglier; 2. that `self.InsertPolicy.InsertAtBottom` does nothing, and it would be useless anyway since the combo isn't editable; 3. the signal `name` shouldn't be overwritten by the slot;

Comment: I have unnested the class as you suggested, and removed "self.InsertPolicy.InsertAtBottom" too.

Back to the main issue, I don't really understand why my instance of "MyTreeAutoDisplay" gets immediately deleted.

I mean, the way it works, I am working on an existing QTree from a .ui file.
Why is the instance destroyed but I can still "physically" see the tree?

Comment: The tree is created on the parent, this is enough to make it persistent. Everything else has no persistent reference, and gets deleted. The garbage collection works by deleting every object as soon as their reference count reaches 0, the tree widget *reference* stops existing on the python side, but the parent takes *ownership* of it (so it's not *destroyed*), the class, instead, has no reference left, it behaves almost like calling a function. Just change to `self.dontDoThis = MyTreeAutoDisplay(self)` and it will work. But, as said, that class is useless right now.

Comment: This worked like a charm!

Thanks a lot.
I will try to keep improving.